# Spring wsdl generation with jaxb:version="2.1"

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, wsdl

I am trying to generate a wsdl that contains the jaxb binding version used in my xsd files. The end result wsdl I want is something to the extent of:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
       jaxb:version="2.1" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.yyy.co.za/zzz" targetNamespace="http://schemas.yyy.co.za/zzz">
```

As opposed to:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.yyy.co.za/zzz" targetNamespace="http://schemas.yyy.co.za/zzz">
```

I use spring 2.5.6 with spring web service components 1.5.5. I suspect the problem is in my Spring context setup which looks like:

```
<bean id="ClientServices" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition">
    <property name="portTypeName" value="ClientServicesPort" />
    <property name="locationUri" value="http://localhost/client/services/ClientServices" />
    <property name="schemaCollection" ref="ClientServicesSchemaCollection" />
    <property name="requestSuffix" value="RequestMessage"/>
    <property name="responseSuffix" value="ResponseMessage" />
</bean>

<bean id="ClientServicesSchemaCollection" class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaCollection">
    <description>
        This bean wrap all the xsds and inlines them as a one.
    </description>
    <property name="inline" value="true" />
    <property name="xsds">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:xsd/sample.xsd</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

part of sample.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <xs:schema xmlns="http://schemas.yyy.co.za/zzz" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jaxb:version="2.1"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need JAXB declarations in WSDL, exactly?

Comment: @lexicore The client using the wsdl wants to generate the client classes from the wsdl directly instead of our xsd files. When I manually add the jaxb:version to the wsdl declaration the client generation works as expected. Our xsd files contain jaxb bindings. Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually all the JAXB-relevant things should be in the bindings, not in WSDL. WSDL should be platform-neutral, making it JAXB-specific or putting JAXB-specifics there is, in my opinion, not the right way. Doesn't it work with the bindings? If not, that may be the right issue to address.

Comment: @lexicore Thanks for the feedback. So what is the standard then? Should I rather supply the client with xsd and bindings to generate the client code from?

Comment: @lexicore Also I am using inline bindings in my xsd file.

Comment: I'd say WSDL (with inlined or imported XSDs) would be the reasonable minimum and standard. You can definitely go further by providing bindings or even a blueprint of the client, but it is not obligatory.

Comment: Inline bindings in XSD are not recommended.

Comment: According to the documentation: The binding declarations are semantically equivalent regardless of which method you choose. Anyway thanks for your help @lexicore.

Comment: Imagine a C# developer who needs to write the client for your web service and sees the JAXB definition in WSDL and schema. Not critical, just not the best practice.